# PS3 game data install of WWE 2k14 stuck on 6%

Tags: ps3, wwe-2k14

I picked up a second hand copy of WWE 2k14 today and I am unable to get past the “Installing Game Data” screen which stops at 6% and I can no longer hear and hard disk activity.

It took a LONG time to download the game data only for the installation to seemingly halt at 6% with no prompt to do anything.

If I quit out the game I need to delete the game data and try again, which I’ve done twice.

Free space is showing as 124GB/149GB, so I have plenty of HDD space remaining.

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe wait even longer. How long did you wait? Other than that, maybe the disk needs cleaning?

Comment: I have just installed another game (AFL Live 2) and it has installed with Game Data without a hitch. I then went back and tried to install WWE 2k14 again and it gets stuck at 6%, no message, no warning just a complete halt in disk activity. The disc _was_ dirty when I bought it, but it is genuinely clean as a whistle now and there's no visible scratches on it. I'm not really sure what else to try. Any post on YT video online complains about the issue but no-one offers any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try clean PS3 gamedata for your game and try install it again. Also check disk for scratches it might be problem aswell.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that - 3 or 4 times. The disc is actually immaculate. I am going to try taking some furniture polish to it and if that doesn't work then I think i'll have to admit defeat.